# In a YAML Build Pipeline, if you have a DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build task does that mean you don't need a NuGetInstaller@0?

Tags: build, azure-pipelines

DevOps build pipelines I have inherited have a **NuGetInstaller@0** task followed by a **DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build** task.

As I understand it **DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build** simply runs `dotnet build`

According to [learn.microsoft.com's dotnet restore page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore)

- `a NuGet restore is run implicitly if necessary when you run ... dotnet build`
- `The dotnet restore command uses NuGet to restore dependencies as well as project-specific tools that are specified in the project file`

Given the above, it would appear that use of a **DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build** task means you don't need a **NuGetInstaller@0** task.

Am I correct in saying that?

Is there any reason anyone can think of as to why someone might have a **NuGetInstaller@0** task followed by a **DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build** task?

The **NuGetInstaller@0** task includes a setting to specify the location of the nuget.exe and the version. The **DotNetCoreCLI@2 Build** task does not so what version does it use and where does it get the nuget.exe it from?

Comment: Yes currently DotNetCoreCLI@2 handle restore imlicitly howver this will be deprecated in future. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/nuget-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines  Use NuGetAuthenticate@1 instead for nuget activities including restore

Comment: @ABC DEF, thanks for the response. I asked about NuGetInstaller@0 and DotNetCoreCLI@2 yet you've responded about NuGetAuthenticate@1.